# Como puedo hacer para que no se cierre las notificaciones asta que termine la app en android studio java

Tags: android, android-notifications

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi problema, necesito ayuda para estas notificaciones en android studio java

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con: "no se cierre las notificaciones asta que termine la app en android studio", revisar [ask].